# LinkedIn API - simple query without logging in

Tags: jquery, api, linkedin-api

I am using the Linked in API to query for a public company profile in an information box.

There is a widget on the site but it's super ugly and uses many iframes so I only want to fetch the company description and use my own style.

I have an API key but all the tutorials dictate how to sign in and manipulate your own profile.

How can I get a simple XML or JSON object containing the information of a public company without having to log in?

I want all users who visit the site to just see the little box with that information without having to log in with their accounts.

Since there is already a widget that does it without logging in (the one found here: https://developer.linkedin.com/plugins/company-profile-plugin)
I should imagine it should be possible to query that information in a different format using the API

Can anyone help?
Nick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it's an either/or proposition. Basically, you can use the pre-built plugins you mention and allow anyone to see what they display (LinkedIn still retains control over what data is shown via the iframes you mention), or if you want to retrieve and format the data as you want, you can use the API, but the API requires the viewer to log in to see the data.

The [API terms of service](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/linkedin-apis-terms-use) prevent you from showing non-authenticated user's data from the API, so if you use it, you'll have to prompt the user to authenticate.